# Invalid destructuring assignment target exception after upgrading to Nodejs 12.2

Tags: node.js

We recently upgraded to `Node 12.2 from 10.15.3`. Below part of function was working fine in 10.15.3, while it started to parse differently after upgrading to 12.2 and throw 'Invalid destructuring assignment target' syntax error.

> undefined:1  (function([ 'context' ]) {
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

Function:

```
    function recompile(context) { 

      var previous = {values: context.previous};

      previous.argnames = previous.values.map(function cmpArgNames(_, i) { return 'previous' + i });

      previous.funcalls = previous.values.map(function cmpFunCalls(f, i) {
        var args = (f.length === 1 ? '(recv)' : '(recv, args, context.storage)');
        return previous.argnames[i] + args;
      });

      var future = {values: context.future};

      future.argnames = future.values.map(function(_, i) { return 'future' + i });

      future.funcalls = future.values.map(function(f, i) {
        var args = (f.length === 2 ? '(recv, rval)' : '(recv, args, rval, context.storage)');

        return future.argnames[i] + args;
      });

      var source = require('util').format(
          ' (function(%s) { \n return function(recv, args) {  \n   try{%s;}catch(e){logProbeErrorMessage(e, recv, context.target, true);}   \n  var rval = context.target.apply(recv, args);  \n  try{%s;}catch(e){logProbeErrorMessage(e, recv, context.target, null, true);}   \n  return rval;  \n   };  \n  })  \n' ,
          ['context'].concat(previous.argnames).concat(future.argnames),
          previous.funcalls.join(';\n'), future.funcalls.join(';\n'));

      var args = [context].concat(previous.values).concat(future.values);

      return eval(source).apply(null, args);
    }
```

**Below 'source' code of function is parsed differently and causes error.**

```
    var source = require('util').format(
          ' (function(%s) { \n return function(recv, args) {  \n   try{%s;}catch(e){logProbeErrorMessage(e, recv, context.target, true);}   \n  var rval = context.target.apply(recv, args);  \n  try{%s;}catch(e){logProbeErrorMessage(e, recv, context.target, null, true);}   \n  return rval;  \n   };  \n  })  \n' ,
          ['context'].concat(previous.argnames).concat(future.argnames),
          previous.funcalls.join(';\n'), future.funcalls.join(';\n'));
```

Below are the parsed strings of source variable:

**10.15.3:**

```
(function(context) { 
 return function(recv, args) {  
   try{;}catch(e){logProbeErrorMessage(e, recv, context.target, true);}   
  var rval = context.target.apply(recv, args);  
  try{;}catch(e){logProbeErrorMessage(e, recv, context.target, null, true);}   
  return rval;  
   };  
  })
```

**12.2.0:**

```
(function([ 'context' ]) { 
 return function(recv, args) {  
   try{;}catch(e){logProbeErrorMessage(e, recv, context.target, true);}   
  var rval = context.target.apply(recv, args);  
  try{;}catch(e){logProbeErrorMessage(e, recv, context.target, null, true);}   
  return rval;  
   };  
  })
```

We can differentiate that the `apostrophe(')` with destructive assignment remaining in the string which is causing the issue in 12.2.0.

What changed with 12.2.0 and How can we fix this?

I expect the output to be same in any of the node versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your question can be reduced to the following.
Why in Node <= 11.x

`require('util').format('test(%s)',['context'])` returns

`test(context)`

while in Node 12.x+ the result is

`test([ 'context' ])`

Internally, since version 12, `format` for `%s` uses [util.inspect()](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args), which was also improved recently.

To solve your problem, use, e.g.

```
['context'].concat(previous.argnames).concat(future.argnames).join(',')
```

or create your own array formatter that accounts for all possible scenarios.

One could argue that the new functionality is more precise and deterministic. Also, it was never locked as a contract.

Comment: This worked. Thanks Alex. Is there's a way to track or identify if a syntax gets deprecated for earlier or improved in future versions. Because handling the code would be challenging if its breaks from version to version.

Comment: @user5189893 I think, you are mixing up couple of things. `util.format()` is not about language syntax, it is a library. Libraries evolve, and you have to regularly check how it behaves. Also, documentation clearly states: `The util module is primarily designed to support the needs of Node.js' own internal APIs.` 
On the other side, if you don't mind me pointing it out, your code is brittle. What if argnames contain nulls? If you were using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals, or, even better, function combinators, you would not get this issue.